# What JavaScript framework do you use with trigger.io? (backbone, knockout, ember, angular)

Tags: trigger.io, forge

What JavaScript framework do you use successfully with Trigger.io? I mean client side JS app frameworks like backbone, knockout, ember, angular?

We use angular.js here but have some significant problems when using router for our app ... see details here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/XGDRAskA8qs . 
Trigger.io and using angular.js router doesnt work together.(at least we could not get it to work)

Do you use some other JS framework you can recommend as working fine with trigger.io using application router capability? (I could see similar router feature in ember or backbone for example)

Comment: Although I am a trigger.io newbie I have not come across issues with Backbone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although we don't endorse one particular library, and our goal is to be compatible with them all, I normally reach for Backbone first when starting a Trigger app. It's simple, lightweight but powerful and has a bunch of [nice](http://perka.github.com/backbone-ui/) [extensions](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette).

Apart from the issues with Angular which we aim to have fixed as part of our next major release (probably end of July '12), we've not had reports of any snags with other libraries apart from [Amber Smalltalk](http://amber-lang.net/), which should be fixed in the same release.

We have demo apps using Backbone and Sencha [here](https://github.com/trigger-corp/Forge-Bootstrap) and [here](https://github.com/trigger-corp/forge-template-sencha-touch), and our initial demo app is written using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Thank you James. Maybe I try to postpone our project ... as we are currently strong in angular.js compaing to almost no knowledge of other frameworks ... I'm willing to help with testing ...

Comment: Sencha also provides and MVC framwork, doesn't it ovrelap with Backbone?

Comment: +1 to backbone - leaving this here just in case... https://github.com/martindavis/trigger-backbone.sync

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jQuery, Backbonejs, Handlebars, Coffeescript, LESS as my framework - they are pretty much all from my Web development effort. Didn't have to change too much.

In fact, so far, I'm finding I have to simplify a LOT of things to get it down to a level where it fits the mobile environment.

Comment: removing a lot of templates that aren't the core part of the app (e.g. side bars, search filters). Basically reducing the app down to the core features - so that is quick to load and you only have so much screen real estate!

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS is one of the best contenders out there as far as JavaScript Frameworks. I ran all the way through the Angular tutorial, created a new Trigger app, and dropped in the tutorial app in place of the default scaffolding.

RAN NO PROBLEM WHAT SO EVER!!! IOS, Android, and WEB

Interestingly enough, I adapted the Angular tutorial with my own data from a server. Even works using XHR requests, and Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

In my opinion, build your app using Angular.JS + Zepto/Jquery.
Use either of those frameworks to add CSS Transitions to your app for your UI.

The reason I recommend making your own UI rather than using something like JQuery Mobile, or Sencha Touch 2 is for the past 3 days I have been doing extensive research and testing on numerouse JS Mobile UI Frameworks, and JQmobi is the only one that came close to being fast but it didnt look vary nice.

Making your own will reduce size of the app, give you full control, and keep the app running smooth..your using will never know its not native ;P